# How to return all rows from a map interface

Tags: go

Basically, I want to return all rows of a specific value in the query which looks as the following

```
var listOf []map[string]interface{}

query2 = strings.Replace(query2, "listOfIds", fmt.Sprintf("%v", listOf[0]["itemIds"]), -1)
```

at the moment the above returns first row as expected since `listOf[0]` but how can I return all of them, is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

To give a bit more context, there are 2 queries. Query 1 generates the ids which then are being past on query 2

```
whereQuery := " WHERE ssItemStoreId = itemIds AND ssItemStoreId = clId" + whereVariables + " AND itemClosedReason != 'Duplicated' AND clId != '' AND ItemArchived = 0"

query1 = query1 + whereQuery

//Data Variables
var listOf []map[string]interface{}
```

The results are being passed on `s.makeSqlQuery(query1, &listOf)` which are being passed on query 2 but there are hundreds of rows and I am only retriving one. I tried using range but I get `index out of range [0] with length 0`

```
query2 = strings.Replace(query2, "listOfIds", fmt.Sprintf("%v", listOf[0]["itemIds"]), -1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you want, 
`range` through the `listOf` slice will give you each element in the slice, then `range` through that element `map[string]interface{}` so you will get all keys and values. use that

Comment: I tried range but doesn't seem to work, did something like this `for key :=  range listOf {query2 = string.Replace(query2, "listOfIds", fmt.Sprintf("%v", listOf[key]["itemIds"]), -1)}`
I am not sure why, got `index out of range [0] with length 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question. provided context isn't enough.but i will add some answer.

You can iterate the "listOf" map and build separate query for each item and execute in db.
Or iterate map and append "itemIds" in to query comman(,) separately and execute in db.

ex 1:

```
    //Your Way
var listOf []map[string]interface{}

listOf = append(listOf, map[string]interface{}{})

listOf[0]["1"] = "1"
listOf[0]["3"] = "3"

query2 := "select * from sometable where id= %s"
ids := ""
for _, v := range listOf {
    for _, v1 := range v {
        // replace logic
        if ids == "" {
            ids = fmt.Sprintf(`%v`, v1)
            continue
        }
        ids += fmt.Sprintf(`,%v`, v1)
    }
}

query2 = fmt.Sprintf(query2, ids) // select * from sometable where id= 3,1
fmt.Println(query2)
```

ex 2:

```
 //  Easy Way
    listOf := make(map[string]interface{})

    listOf["1"] = "1"
    listOf["2"] = "2"

    query2 := "select * from sometable where id= %s"
    ids := ""
    for _, v := range listOf {
        // replace logic
        if ids == "" {
            ids = fmt.Sprintf(`%v`, v)
            continue
        }
        ids += fmt.Sprintf(`,%v`, v)

    }

    query2 = fmt.Sprintf(query2, ids) // select * from sometable where id= 1,2

    fmt.Println(query2)
```

Comment: Thank you, first example sort of works though I get `runtime error: index out of range [19] with length 1` second example won't work as I can pass the results from query one to the index `s.makeSqlQuery(query1, &listOf)`  

`cannot use &listOf (value of type *map[string]interface{}) as *[]map[string]interface{} value in argument to s.makeSqlQuery`

Comment: actually never mind, first example was perfect! with a slight tweak which you already provided on comment `replace logic` Thank you